# React carousel custom transform (not horizontal/vertical)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, carousel

I am a beginner to ReactJS and carousels. I want to code a carousel that looks like this, with autoplay rotation:

[image]

I think I understand the general approach of carousels:

- create `data` array containing objects;
- export a component that maps each element of `data` (`data.map((obj, index) => (...))`) to an HTML element;
- add a state variable `slideInd` to the component which will represent the value of the `margin-left` CSS property of the 0th element of array `data`;
- use the `useEffect` hook to trigger an update to the state of the 0th array element's `margin-left` CSS property, creating the effect of things sliding left (though it's only modifying the state of the 0th element);
- in the same `useEffect` `setTimeout()` function, make sure to cycle back to the 0th element if your state has reached the length of the `data` array;

For example,

```js
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";
import styled from "@emotion/styled"
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const Wrapper = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    overflow-x: visible;
`;

const Slide = styled.div`
    width: 100%;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    outline: 3px solid green;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    &::before{
        content: "";
        min-height: 100px;
    }
`

const data = [
    {'id': uuidv4(), 'title': 'slide1'},
    {'id': uuidv4(), 'title': 'slide2'},
    {'id': uuidv4(), 'title': 'slide3'},
]

const Test = ({ ...props }) => {   

    const [slideInd, setSlideInd] = useState(0)

    useEffect(() => {
        const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
            // If at the end, scroll all the way back to the beginning
            // ideal function: go back one step at a time instead
            const n = slideInd >= data.length - 1 ? 0 : slideInd + 1
            setSlideInd(n)
            console.log(`Rotate margin left 0th element by: -${slideInd*100}%`)
        // Here, "2000" is the delay miliseconds that the timer waits
        // before the "timeout" function is executed -- this is the
        // miliseconds before each slide "slides"
        }, 2000)
        // Clear the timeout to avoid any memory leaks
        return () => clearTimeout(timeout)
    }, [slideInd])

    return (
        <Wrapper {...props}>
            {data.map((obj, index) => (
                <Slide 
                    style={{
                        marginLeft: index === 0 ? `-${slideInd * 100}%` : undefined,
                    }}
                    // Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop
                    key={obj.id}
                >
                    {obj.title}
                </Slide>
            ))}
        </Wrapper>
    )
}

export default Test
```

##### Edit: attempted answer

If I then try to change it to accomplish my idea, I thought to:

- Instead of using an index that controls a CSS property `margin-left`, mutate the `data` array's state itself
- In `useEffect`, update `data` via putting the first element to the last position

```js
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";
import styled from "@emotion/styled"
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";


const Wrapper = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    overflow-x: visible;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-start;
    height: 50vh;
`;

const Slide = styled.div`
    flex-shrink: 0;
    outline: 3px solid green;
    transition: all 1.75s cubic-bezier(0.25, 1, 0.25, 1);
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 620px;
    &::before{
        content: "";
        min-height: 400px;
    }
`

const Test = ({ ...props }) => {   
    
    const [data, setData] = useState([
        {'id': uuidv4(), 'title': 'slide1'},
        {'id': uuidv4(), 'title': 'slide2'},
        {'id': uuidv4(), 'title': 'slide3'},
    ])

    useEffect(() => {
        const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
            // Push first element to end of array
            let el = data.shift()
            data[data.length] = el
            setData([...data])
        }, 3600)
        // Clear the timeout to avoid any memory leaks
        return () => clearTimeout(timeout)
    }, [data])
    

    return (
        <Wrapper {...props}>
            {data.map((obj, index) => (
                <Slide 
                    style={{
                        marginLeft: `${2.25 * index}%`,
                        marginTop: `-${1.25 * index}%`,
                        zIndex: -index,
                        // Opacity modeled by func y with intercept (0, 1) & horizontal asymptote at x=0
                        // a hyperbola, y = 1 / (x + 1)
                        // to steepen the curve to avoid index=1 opacity=0.5, we just add an exponent
                        // to the denominator, e.g. y = 1 / (x + 1)^4
                        // This creates the effect of the foreground element
                        // being opaque, and the other elements quickly fade in the background
                        // Design alternative: just keep first element
                        // opacity: (1 - (index / 1)),
                        opacity: (1 / Math.pow(index + 1, 4)),
                    }}
                    // Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop
                    key={obj.id}
                >
                    {obj.title}
                </Slide>
            ))}
            
        </Wrapper>
    )
}

export default Test
```

This does constantly rotate the elements of the array, but it lacks:

- fluid transitions: the elements re-animate themselves from the center of the page each event cycle;

Is there a way to accomplish this shuffling effect without having to update the value of the `data` array itself?

Thank you!!